# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject on Person Accounts (specifically Contact fields)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, person-accounts, sales-cloud

Has anyone been able to use the [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) function on an Account/Contact in Person Accounts (specifically Contact fields such as Email, FirstName, LastName)? I'm able to retrieve the contact using [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) but I obviously can't write to Contacts as it is **read-only** on Person Accounts.

I've tried replacing "Email" below with "Account.PersonEmail", "PersonEmail", "Email__pc". None of the above works.

```
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account','0031U00000KE9UTQA1','Email','info@salesforce.com')
```

Comment: You are specifying 'Account' as object, but using Contacts ID as the specified ID in your call (starting with 003). You should specify the object type as Contact. Never heard Contacts being read-only for PersonAccounts. If I'm not wrong the Email field is just called "PersonEmail".

Comment: I’ve also tried the AccountId and PersonContactId but to no avail. The issue is that the AMPscript function only can update objects and PersonAccount is not an object.

Comment: "In the newer APIs, the Contact is completely read-only if it is attached to an account (as in, a Person Account). Instead, use the same field on the account, and update that instead." https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xrHIAQ

Comment: Thanks @Rain for the help. "PersonEmail" is correct. There were some validation errors in SalesCloud on some formulas which was causing the record to not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were some formula validation errors on SalesCloud which prevented any updates to the Person Account record. The correct AMPscript is:

```
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account',@PersonContactId,'PersonEmail','info@salesforce.com')
```

Comment: did you get this to work with a contact ID where you have @PersonContactId? I can only get it to work with an actual account ID, but not with the PersonContactID

Comment: Make sure you’re updating on the Account object.

Comment: I was, but no dice. I'll try again.